# Error in file already exists

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to create file for an account, after checking if file already exists or not!   But I got stuck, because I am getting an unexpected run time error!

### 1st run

Enter the name of account : Hassan

Account created

### 2nd run

Enter account name: Hassan

Account already exists

Enter the name of account : Hassan

Account created

This is the problem!!! and it creates file with the name "assan"

### CODE

```
/*
********************
1.  ADD ACCOUNT
********************
*/
void add_account(){

system("cls");
cout<<"\n\t******************************************\n";
cout<<"\t\tADD ACCOUNT MENU\n";
cout<<"\t******************************************\n";



//Taking account name
again:
Account new_account;
cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter the name of account : ";
cin.ignore(); //for clearing buffer
cin.getline(new_account.account_name,79);

if(create_file_for_account(new_account.account_name)==0)
    goto again;


cout<<endl<<endl; system("pause");
return;
}

/*
********************
1(a). CREATE FILE OF ACCOUNT
********************
*/
int create_file_for_account(char file_name[])
{
//Check if file exists already
if(does_file_exist(file_name)){
    cout<<"\n\nSorry, account already exists!";
    return 0;
}

ofstream account;

account.open(file_name,ios::out);

//Check if file created successfully
if(account.good()){
    cout<<"File created";
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}

}

/*
********************
1(b). CHECK IF FILE EXISTS
********************
*/
bool does_file_exist(char file_name[])
{

ifstream check(file_name, ios::ate);
if(check)
    return true;
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Please help, I was trying for hours to catch error, but I can't
As I am beginner in C++ :p Please ...

Comment: Can you please add the missing piece of code which prints this "Please enter account name again "

Comment: Sorry, actually it is goto statement which will take it to input statement again

Comment: I would just like to point out that the usage of the `system` function is considered to be bad practice. I guess it is fine if, as you say, you are a beginner. But please don't rely on `system` in the future

Comment: Ok, then please suggest the better way for future

Comment: Well, seeing as how you are using `system("cls");` (`cls` being a Windows command), I would recommend using the Windows API (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @CodeLearner Anyway, does your code crash, or does it run and produce unexpected output? You haven't told us much about the actual problem

Comment: Although "goto" does have its uses, this style is generally considered poor quality coding considering the features the language provides. Did you find out about labels and gotos yourself or from a tutor?

Comment: I found this my self, it's easier to use for me as I am beginner, by the way how can I sent back user to input name again if he enters wrong name without GOTO ?

Comment: @CodeLearner: This is a different question. If you were to post it as such, I am sure we would be willing to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the "cin.ignore" will discard only the first character of the input (if there is one) (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

So I'd assume that the "H" somehow got ignored...

Comment: SO what can I do please suggest ?

Comment: The question is: why do you want to clear the buffer in the first place? AFAIK this should perfectly work without clearing it (unless you have users which randomly press keys while running the application). Please note that cout and cin are completely unrelated streams. So you don't have to worry about reading stuff you just wrote with cout.

Comment: Don't use "ignore". Just read the line and then parse the line (trim it, etc). Handling input like this is hard, there are so many exceptions to cope with.

Comment: I removed cin.ignore(); but now it is printing cout statement two times